# check if an object has same field's value ​​as defined in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
var Items = new Array({ name: "aaa", field: "bbb", val: true },
                      { name: "ccc", field: "ddd", val: false })
```

I want to check if a certain object has same field's value ​​as defined in the `field` & `val` of the array.

I did this:

```
var obj = {bbb: false, ddd: false} #(I'm getting the obj from API, but this is what I have when I print obj to log)

_.each(Items, function(item){
   if (obj[item.field] === item.val)  
     console.log(obj[item.field],"=",item.val);
});
```

But I got `undefind=undefined`.

When I tried `obj['bbb']` OR `obj[String(item.field)]`, I got the value.

Also, see following logs inside the loop:

```
console.log(typeof item.field, typeof "bbb");
=> string string
console.log(obj["bbb"], obj[item.field], obj[String(item.field)], item.field);
=> false undefined false "bbb"
```

**Does Anybody know why this happens?**

Comment: An objects field name needs to be a string, you seem to be trying to retrieve a property named `true` or `false`.

Comment: No, the value is `true` or `false`. Not the field name...

Comment: Yes but when you are checking `obj[item.val]` you are essentially checking `obj[true]` or `obj[false]`.

Comment: Oops... right. See updated answer. But still I can't access `obj[item.field]`.

Comment: Can you show a sample object that you are comparing to? Or better yet add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: I added my obj format.

Comment: You haven't updated the way you are logging your results... I added a fiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An objects property name must be a **string**, any string is valid including an empty string (the truth is the same is really true of arrays, except that the numbers get converted to a string (for example `Items[0]` is really `Items["0"]`)).

When you are comparing to `obj[item.val]` you are (for the sample array you provided) checking for a property name that is a `boolean` which isn't valid. When you instead use `obj[String(item.val)]` you are first converting the value `true` or `false` to a string so it becomes `"true"` or `"false"`.

Here's a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNAk7/1/)

Comment: Just remove the `obj[String(item.field)]`. It will not convert the value true or false to a string so it becomes "true" or "false", since `item.field` is "bbb" and not `boolian`.

Answer (score 0):

To compare objects, it's simpler to just use `_.isEqual`(see http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual). Javascript has some very wierd quirks, for example http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: Thanks. But `_.isEqual(item.field, "bbb")` gives me `false`. Somehow, even the type of them is string, they are not the same... So I can't do `obj[item.field]`.

Comment: You should be doing `_.isEqual(obj, item)`

Comment: But this shouldn't be equal. Only the value of the field `bbb` should be equal to the val(true) in the array.